# How to determine a server's connection time is greater than 10 secs. and if so, move on to next server

Tags: ssh, connection, timeout

I've seen all the examples for setting a connectTimeout, however, I am looping through a list of servers and if the current server takes more than 10sec, then move on to the next one if not, then assign this server to a variable.

Based on knowledge learned in previous question, my script is as follows

```
SERVERS="abc123 abc124 abc125"

for n in $SERVERS ; do
 if [ ssh -o connectTimeout=10 "$n" ] ; then
   SERVER="$n"
 if
done
```

Obviously this doesn't work. The if throws [too many arguments] and I actually want to say `if [ ssh "$n" <= connectTime=10 ] ; then SERVER="$n"...etc`. however, I'm not a bash expert, so I don't know if that is an acceptable argument or not, so it's why I'm reaching out to the experts. Thanks for all feedback.

Comment: How is setting the connect timeout not a solution? If the connection attempt times out, ssh will fail and your script can go on to the next server.

Comment: That's fine, if it didn't return too many arguments. It's why I want to attempt the latter. If it doesn't timeout, then SERVER="$n" should have one value and the loop should end, however, i'm not getting that far.

Comment: wanted to post a follow-up: I reran the original script, output at "if statement" [:too many arguments]

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ ssh -o connectTimeout=10 "$n" ]
```

Remove the "[" and "]" characters here. "[" and "]" aren't part of the `if` statement syntax. They invoke a [command named `[`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test) (also known as the `test` command) which performs certain kinds of tests. You commonly see `if` and `[` used together, but they'e two separate commands.

Something like this should work:

```
for n in $SERVERS
do
    if ssh -o connectTimeout=10 "$n"
    then
        SERVER="$n"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!